# xml parsing using SAXParser

Tags: java, blackberry, xml-parsing, saxparser

I am working with one application in which `SAXparsing` is placed. To get the `City & State` name from latitude and longitude I'm using `Google API`. Google API url [google api](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=23.045948,72.3749&sensor=true)

I want to get `long_name` `short_name` & `type` of header Tag `address_component` .

All the information I am getting successfully from this XML but problem is that when I am trying to get `type` Tag value . There are Two `type` tag in this header and I am always getting second `type` tag value .

Sample  XML:

```
<address_component>
<long_name>Gujarat</long_name>
<short_name>Gujarat</short_name>
<type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
<type>political</type>
</address_component>
```

How can I get `type` Tag value is `administrative_area_level_1` as well as `political`?

Comment: I think you should check this: [Android - SAX Parsing Example](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-sax-parsing-example/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across the following link which is really easy to give a start-
 http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/12/parse-read-xml-file-java-sax-parser.html

Answer (score 0):

I add the data into one file named as location.xml(if you get this from web do your own logic for getting data after getting that data convert into Inputstream pass it to following code) i wrote a method in that you can get it

```
public void ReadAndWriteXMLFileUsingSAXParser(){

        try
        {
            DefaultHandler handler = new MyHandler();
//              parseXmlFile("infilename.xml", handler, true);
            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
            InputStream rStream = null;
            rStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("location.xml");
            saxParser.parse(rStream, handler);
        }catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

This is MyHandler class. your final data stored into one vector called as "data"

```
class MyHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    String rootname;Attributes atr;
    private boolean flag=false;private Vector data;
    public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName,
                             String qName, Attributes atts)  {
     rootname=localName;
     atr=atts;

     if(rootname.equalsIgnoreCase("address_component")){
         data=new Vector();
         flag=true;
     }


    }
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length){
        String value=new String(ch,start,length);
        if(flag)
        {
            if(rootname.equalsIgnoreCase("type")){
                data.addElement(value) ;
                System.out.println("++++++++++++++"+value);
            }
            if(rootname.equalsIgnoreCase("long_name")){
                data.addElement(value) ;
                System.out.println("++++++++++++++"+value);
            }
            if(rootname.equalsIgnoreCase("short_name")){
                data.addElement(value) ;
                System.out.println("++++++++++++++"+value);
            }
        }

    }
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName){
        rootname=localName;
         if(rootname.equalsIgnoreCase("address_component")){
             flag=false;
         }
    }
}
```

you can find all data into the data vector and also you can find the data onconsole
as

> ++++++++++++++Gujarat
>
> ++++++++++++++Gujarat
>
> ++++++++++++++administrative_area_level_1
>
> ++++++++++++++political

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/) tutorial. This will help you to parse xml file using sax parser.